# Laravel webhook client error 405 on whatsapp webhook url

Tags: laravel, facebook, webhooks, whatsapp

I tried use laravel for webhook in whatsapp cloud but it show this error

Facebook error

[image: 1]

and in the ngrok show this error

Ngrok error

[image: 2]

I use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-webhook-client for the webhook

Comment: Looks like you only have a route for POST set up - but the initial verification step of the webhook integration happens via GET.

Comment: thanks, I've already made GET route, and it still shows the same error in Facebook, 
if I look at the glitch app that was used for demo when the token is correct its return res.status(200).send(challenge);
and I am confused about how to translate it to PHP/laravel, when i return response($req['hub_challenge'], 200), facebook still show the same error

Comment: this is the glitch demo app
https://glitch.com/edit/?fbclid=IwAR2iCBBqdS2FrR6VJDhBeGvfo2m9i3UI3EfSqU5H1LbEXjGocQebVzDHoLo#!/whatsapp-cloud-api-echo-bot

Comment: It's a GET request, so you should be able to easily test what response your bot actually gives, directly inside your own browser.

Comment: sorry for my bad English, I knew what the bot in the Glitch app gives, but i want to make a controller in laravel where it can verify when i connect it with WhatsApp webhooks, the glitch app just for reference how it works, should i make another question which is clearer ?

Comment: What you need to implement for the verification step, is explained in detail here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#create-endpoint

Comment: yeah and I've returned 200 and the challenge but it's still an error

Comment: As I said, you can easily verify that your script gives the correct response, by calling it (with the appropriate GET parameters set) directly in your browser.

Comment: the thing is I don't know what correct response for Facebook request, I only know it should return 200 and the challenge code, should i return it in string or JSON, i tried both but still error

Comment: _Just_ the challenge value, nothing else.

Comment: I've return the challenge value but still error, in my controller i use this
return response($req['hub_challenge'], 200);

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, Whatsapp webhook servers won't accept links which are exposed by Ngrok as a Callback url.

Because these kind of urls have been identified as malicious and/or abusive.

You need to go with your script on a server and use as the webhook a valid domain with certified ssl like

https://example.com/webhook

https://listener.example.com/webhook

Answer (score 0):

You need to return just the `hub_challenge`.
This worked for me `return $req['hub_challenge'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet("webhook")]
public IActionResult Get(string hub_mode, string hub_challenge, string hub_verify_token)
{
      // You can access the query settings here and do whatever you need.

      // For example, you can check if hub_verify_token equals an expected value:
      if (hub_verify_token == "123")
      {
          return Ok(hub_challenge); // Returns hub_challenge as a response if the token is correct.
      }
      other
      {
          return BadRequest("Invalid Token");
      }
}
```